# Can XBAP file be hosted on a web page?

Tags: c#, wpf, web

I have a wpf brwoser application which opens a xbap on the browser. Is it possible to host this on a web page?
Im a beginner in wpf so im not sure if im looking at a wrong usage of xbap. Please provide an answer also if its not possible, other ways of hoting application on the web are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: xbap was intended for local intranet use. Hosting it publicly nowadays would mean fighting all the security settings. It's not a good path to go on.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/09/ie9-xbaps-disabled-in-the-internet-zone/

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Silverlight](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=149156) was/is the technology created to run Xaml in a plugin. `XBAP` is not as robust as Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks. But how widely is silverlight used? Is it the best way ?

Comment: @skyx Silverlight at this point is good for Line of Business applications which have a need to circumvent being installed. Frankly if you can use WPF or .Net Core instead, that would be a better route.